# Remember non-recursive function result

Tags: python

I have a costly non-recursive function and I would like to memorize the result to a dictionary thus saving time by checking the result in the dictionary.

The function has 3 parameters:

```
def slow_func(a,b,c)
```

Currently, I'm saving an object in a deque:

```
memory = deque([], 1000)
...
{(a,b,c):result}, {(a,b,c):result}, {(a,b,c):result}
```

and I check if (a,b,c) is in the dictionary then show the result.

Is there a faster way to save the result?

Edit:

- The inputs are different almost 40% of the time.
- Inputs a and b are `numpy.ndarray`
- return is `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Are the inputs `(a,b,c)` always the same or are they unique?

Comment: Why a deque and not a dictionary?

Comment: I cycle through 1000 stored values, so I decided to used deque. a,b and c are quite big

Comment: What is the type of the return?

Comment: The return is np.ndarray

Answer (score 2):

Edit: OP has updated the question to include datatypes, but I am leaving the answer up as it can be useful for others.

If the datatypes of a,b,c are not mutable (tuples are ok, lists are not) there is a built in function decorator for this:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def slow_func(a,b,c):
      ....
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, I thought of lru_cache too. I get TypeError: unhashable type. I probably should do a custom decorator.

Comment: You hadn't put the input datatypes when i answered.  Yes it won't work with mutable data types

Comment: [`@functools.lru_cache(user_function)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache): "Since a dictionary is used to cache results, the positional and keyword arguments to the function must be hashable."

Comment: Sorry Christian, I had it in mind when I edited the question but wasn't on time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use caching with types like `numpy.array` as function parameter, which is mutable and not hashable, one can use the following solution:

```
from functools import lru_cache, wraps
import numpy as np


def np_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    """LRU cache implementation for functions whose FIRST parameter is a numpy array"""
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(np_array, *args, **kwargs):
            hashable_array = array_to_tuple(np_array)
            return cached_wrapper(hashable_array, *args, **kwargs)

        @lru_cache(*args, **kwargs)
        def cached_wrapper(hashable_array, *args, **kwargs):
            array = tuple(map(tuple, np_array))
            return function(array, *args, **kwargs)

        def array_to_tuple(np_array):
            """Iterates recursivelly."""
            try:
                return tuple(array_to_tuple(_) for _ in np_array)
            except TypeError:
                return np_array

        # copy lru_cache attributes over too
        wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info
        wrapper.cache_clear = cached_wrapper.cache_clear

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

# use decorator to cache
@np_cache(maxsize=256)
def multiply(array, factor):
    print("Calculating...")
    return factor*array

# execute function once 
multiply(array, 2)
```

> Calculating...
>
> array([[ 2,  4,  6], [ 8, 10, 12]])

```
# execute function twice
multiply(array, 2)
```

> Calculating...
>
> array([[ 2,  4,  6], [ 8, 10, 12]])

```
multiply.cache_info()
```

> ***CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=256, currsize=1)***

git code [here](https://gist.github.com/Susensio/61f4fee01150caaac1e10fc5f005eb75).

Comment: Out of curiosity: How faster was this compared to your original method?

Comment: Almost one out of three calls is cached

Comment: There is an error: `NameError: name 'np_array' is not defined`. It's on line `array = tuple(map(tuple, np_array))`